# How to reach Reykjavík-Keflavík airport late in the evening from the Blue Lagoon?

Tags: public-transport, iceland, kef

I have a flight very early in the morning from Keflavik and I'm considering spending the day before at the Blue Lagoon, which is very close to the airport, until closing time, which is around 11 p.m., and then take the bus (or other means) to the airport.

I asked at the tourist information center in Reykjavik and I was told that the last bus from the Blue Lagoon to Keflavik is at 10 p.m. but judging from the official [Blue Lagoon site](http://www.bluelagoon.com/transportation-schedule/) the last bus is at 2:30 p.m.!

Are there buses operated from other companies with different scheduele? If not, how can I reach the airport otherwise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://www.re.is/blue-lagoon-schedule) you can find the schedule from Reykjavik Excursions and as you can see during summer time they operate till 22.00 indeed. If you want to be sure, just arrange it with the bus driver on your way to Blue Lagoon from Reykjavik.

Happy visit to Iceland! :)

Comment: I've been told that but it's weird because the [official blue lagoon site](http://www.bluelagoon.com/transportation-schedule/) show different schedules for buses operated by the very same Reykjavik Excursions...

Comment: Also, how do you book it. looks like that from the re.is main page there's no blue lagoon in the drop down lists...

Comment: well, when I was in Iceland I didn't use the public transport so I can't tell you from my experience... But even in February there were some buses coming in and out of the parking lot in front of the blue lagoon every 10 minutes. I just can't believe that there would no be a regular service to the airport in the high touristic season.

Are you in Iceland right now? Check it maybe with the info at BSI bus station in Reykjavik